# Can git show files in order they have been merged into branch

Tags: git

I'm trying to automate a process of migrating database a bit. I wonder can I sort migration scripts by the order they have been merged into develop branch and then by original commit they have been added if they were merged in one merge commit.

This way the ordering would be automatically correct.

Comment: Why is that necessary? Typically you'd include a timestamp in the migration filename, so that they sort the right way by default.

Comment: No, using timestamp isn't right. Because what matters is the order in which migrations have been merged into main branch.

Answer (score 1):

Use `--diff-filter=A` to limit only to added files. Then you can format the log to show only files. Here's a good start.

```
git log --oneline --diff-filter=A --stat <migration dir>
```

UPDATE: Then you can play with custom `--format` to bring it down to just files. Like RomainValeri commented, `--name-only --pretty=format:""`.

```
git log --name-only --pretty=format:"" --diff-filter=A <migration dir>
```

Comment: `--name-only --pretty=format:""` to suppress all output other than files

Comment: I think to achieve my goal you need to add `--topo-order`.